# jwplayer not loading flash.swf

Tags: jwplayer

I've been trying to add the jwplayer to my site for live streaming but it is not loading the flash.swf file. This my configuration.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var flashvars = {
    file:'filename',

    streamer:'rtmp://example/example/_definst_/username=example/password=example/'
  };

  swfobject.embedSWF('assets/flash/jwplayer/player.swf','container','480','270','9.0.115','false', flashvars,

   {allowfullscreen:'true',allowscriptaccess:'always'},
   {id:'jwplayer',name:'jwplayer'}

  );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `player.swf` in your application root and also try to load the `.flv or .mp4` files from your application directly as file instead of stream. If that works then your configuration is right. then go for Stream.

For more configuration related information follow [official guide](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15995/jw-embedder-reference-guide) from  Longtailvideo
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15995/jw-embedder-reference-guide

i thought to enter this in comment first ,its going lengthy so entered as answer